# While Loop will not Execute in C

Tags: c, loops, pointers, while-loop, scanf

When I run this program, everything is executed except for the block of while loops at the end. I am asked for the "number of symbols to print per line" and then the program ends. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num_lines;
    printf("Enter a number of lines, greater than or equal to 7, to print :  ");
    scanf("%d", &num_lines);

    if (num_lines < 7) {
        while ( num_lines < 7 ) {
            printf("Enter the number of lines to print\nMust be greater than or equal to 7 :  ");
            scanf("%d", &num_lines);
        }
    }

    char symbol;
    printf("Choose a symbol/character to be displayed */&/+/0/x :  ");
    scanf("%s", &symbol);

    int num_symbols;
    printf("Enter the number of symbols to print per line :  ");
    scanf("%d", &num_symbols);

    if (num_symbols < 7 || num_symbols > 27) {
        num_symbols = 19;
    }

    while (num_lines > 0) {
        while (num_symbols > 0) {
            printf("%s", symbol);
            --num_symbols;
        }
        printf("\n");
        --num_lines;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Simple question, *is `num_lines` > 0?*

Comment: Yes, input 8 for num_lines, * for symbol, and 10 for num_symbols.

Comment: O/T - no need for `if (num_lines < 7) {` .. if that's true the body of `while ( num_lines < 7 ) {` will execute, otherwise it won't

Comment: `scanf("%s", &symbol);` --> `scanf(" %c", &symbol);`... `printf("%s", symbol);` --> `printf("%c", symbol);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code snippet

```
char symbol;
printf("Choose a symbol/character to be displayed */&/+/0/x :  ");
scanf("%s", &symbol);
```

there is used invalid format specifier `%s`. Instead use format specifier `" %c"`

```
char symbol;
printf("Choose a symbol/character to be displayed */&/+/0/x :  ");
scanf(" %c", &symbol);
```

Also in this call of printf

```
       printf("%s", symbol);
```

you have to use the format specifier `%c`

```
       printf("%c", symbol);
```

To provide that these loops would work correctly

```
   while (num_lines > 0) {
       while (num_symbols > 0) {
           printf("%s", symbol);
           --num_symbols;
       }
       printf("\n");
       --num_lines;
   }
```

you need to use an intermediate variable to store the value of `num_symbols` between iterations of the outer loop. For example

```
   while (num_lines > 0) {
       int n = num_symbols; 
       while (n > 0) {
           printf("%c", symbol);
           --n;
       }
       printf("\n");
       --num_lines;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a very severe bug,

```
char symbol;
scanf("%s", &symbol);
```

is undefined behavior, because `"%s"` expects a pointer to a `char` array of at least size 2. In your case, you are passing a pointer to a single `char`, the effects of such code is undefined.

Instead, it could be (*at least*)

```
char symbol[2];
scanf("%1s", symbol);
```

Or, see @[BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042881/while-loop-will-not-execute-in-c?noredirect=1#comment81032829_47042881)'s suggestion.

After invoking *undefined behavior*, the program's memory could become corrupted so the rest of the program could fail for multiple reasons.

You also, never check that `scanf("%d", ...)` was succesful potentially another cause for *undefined behavior*.

ALWAYS check that `scanf()` returns the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's boil the problem down to it's core: you're overwriting num_lines on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) because you're asking to read a string when you really want a character. When scanf creates the string, it will be null terminated ... and so add a [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) after the single char on the stack. One of the joys of working with pointers in C.

(This isn't a stack overflow but rather just a stack overwrite.)

Here is a minimal example of failure. Just change the `%s` to `%c` and everything will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int num_lines;
  sscanf("7", "%d", &num_lines);
  printf("at first, num_lines is %d\n", num_lines);
  char symbol;
  sscanf("x", "%s", &symbol);
  printf("but now, num_lines has become %d\n", num_lines);
  printf("value changed because the second sscanf overwrote\n");
  printf("      num_lines on the call stack!!!\n");
  return; 
}
```

You'll notice that I'm lazy; use `sscanf` during testing to have less annoying typing to perform.

Run it and you get:

```
$ gcc scan.c ; ./a.out
at first, num_lines is 7
but now, num_lines has become 0
value changed because the second sscanf overwrote
      num_lines on the call stack!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with char variable `symbol`. You are declaring `symbol` as character variable and reading it as string. There is one more issue. While you are using `scanf` to read string or character and number at the same time always read the string or char value before reading a numeric value. The reason is `scanf` also read one more character `\n` for which it always creates problem.

now change your code like below:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num_lines;
    char symbol;
    printf("Choose a symbol/character to be displayed */&/+/0/x :  ");
    scanf("%c", &symbol);
    printf("Enter a number of lines, greater than or equal to 7, to print :  ");
    scanf("%d", &num_lines);

if (num_lines < 7) {
    while ( num_lines < 7 ) {
        printf("Enter the number of lines to print\nMust be greater than or equal to 7 :  ");
        scanf("%d", &num_lines);
    }
}   

int num_symbols;
printf("Enter the number of symbols to print per line :  ");
scanf("%d", &num_symbols);

if (num_symbols < 7 || num_symbols > 27) {
    num_symbols = 19;
}

while (num_lines > 0) {
    while (num_symbols > 0) {
        printf("%s", symbol);
        --num_symbols;
    }
    printf("\n");
    --num_lines;
 }
  return 0;//you have to return a value
}
```

if still giving you any problem just hard coded `symbol = '*';` and try.